# Using SFML to draw text from a function

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm trying to use a function to set a text to display on SFML based on the input parameters.

The function is of type Text and returns a text object. I've added `cout` statements to determine where the error is occurring. The text is as follows:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "functions.h"
using namespace std;
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>                    // include the SFML Graphics Library
using namespace sf;

Text showPoints(int& points, bool addPoints, bool isPlayer){
    cout << "Function called " << endl;
    string disPoints;
    Text toDisp;
    Font pointFont;
    if(addPoints){
        points += 1;
    }
    cout << "Points added" << endl;
    if(!pointFont.loadFromFile("data/arial.ttf") ){
        cout << "could not load font" << endl;
    }
    cout << "Loaded fonts" << endl;
    if(isPlayer){
        cout << "isPlayer conditional" << endl;
        disPoints = "Player Points: ";
        toDisp.setPosition(50, 800);
        toDisp.setFont(pointFont);
        toDisp.setString(disPoints);
        toDisp.setFillColor(Color::White);
        toDisp.setCharacterSize(30);
    }
    else if(!isPlayer){
        cout << "isAI conditional" << endl;
        disPoints = "AI Points: ";
        toDisp.setPosition(1000, 200);
        toDisp.setFont(pointFont);
        toDisp.setString(disPoints);
        toDisp.setFillColor(Color::White);
        toDisp.setCharacterSize(30);
    }

    cout << "Conditions passed" << endl;
    return toDisp;
}

//usual SFML stuff... under the while(window.isOpen()), before the 
//window.display() and events check

        cout << "Error on function?" << endl;
        window.draw(showPoints(playerPoints, 0, 1));
        cout << "First function passed" << endl;
        window.draw(showPoints(AIPoints, 0, 0));
```

I expect that the text would show in the appropriate positions in the SFML window. However, the terminal outputs this and the window crashes:

```
Error on function?
Function called 
Points added
Loaded fonts
isPlayer conditional
Conditions passed

Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

It must be a problem with the window.draw() function as the second draw function is not called. So is it legal to call a function of type `Text` in the window.draw()? If not, how should I go about this? Google searches yielded nothing helpful on this issue.

Comment: Reference about [https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.0/classsf_1_1Text.php#a2927805d1ae92d57f15034ea34756b81](setFont) on Text states : *The font argument refers to **a font that must exist as long as the text uses it**. Indeed, the text doesn't store its own copy of the font, but rather **keeps a pointer to the one** that you passed to this function. If the font is destroyed and the text tries to use it, the behavior is undefined.* Now, do you see your mistake? `pointFont` is local inside function, and you return `Text` instance which refers to this variable, so you have UB.

Comment: You can make some struct wrapper which will store `sf::Text` with `sf::Font` to prolong Font lifetime.

Comment: @rafix07 That makes sense. I got it to work by making a new ```Text``` object in main and setting that equal to the function, then loading a font for it in main. Thank you so much!